# IE7 with ul and li in css table

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-tables

I have a CSS table I made that looks good on all browsers except IE7. In IE7, the ul cells are been out of set.

link:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107452929/issue/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ul ul{
   *left: 0;
   *margin: 0;
   *padding: 0;
}
```

if that does not work you may have to add a negative left margin to the ul ul.

Adding the * will target only ie7

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: none` and `clear:both` to your class- `likeAndselete`.

This will give you the same look and feel in all the browsers